# Definition of Global Variable Resetting

Tags: swift

I have a class designed to take the temperature data from an API for a specific date and add it to a dictionary. The URL for the API is stored in a global variable called **baseURL**. It is defined at the beginning as an empty string, but is later changed. My class is below:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void

class WeatherManager: NSObject {

var baseURL: String = ""
var data: String = ""
static let sharedInstance = WeatherManager()


func getRandomUser(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
    println("Starting getRandomUser")
    let route = self.baseURL
    println(self.baseURL)
    makeHTTPGetRequest(route, onCompletion: { json, err in
        onCompletion(json as JSON)
    })
}

func makeHTTPGetRequest(path: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let json:JSON = JSON(data: data)
        onCompletion(json, error)
        if error != nil {
            println("No Error")
        } else {
            println("Error")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

func addData() {
    WeatherManager.sharedInstance.getRandomUser { json in
        var jsonData = json["response"]["version"]
        self.data = "\(jsonData)"
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Weather Data Update"
            if self.data != "null" {
                println("Value:\(self.data)")
                alert.message = "The weather data was updated successfully."
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alert.show()
            } else {
                println("Error Reading Data")
                println(self.data)
                alert.message = "HealthTrendFinder encountered an error while updating data."
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alert.show()
            }
        })
    }
}

func updateWeatherHistory() {
    println(self.baseURL)
    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    println("Weather Updating...")
    // This sets the start date to midnight of the current date if no start date has been set.
    if StorageManager.getValue(StorageManager.StorageKeys.WeatherStartDate) == nil {
        let startDate: NSDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
        StorageManager.setValue(startDate, forKey: StorageManager.StorageKeys.WeatherStartDate)

    }

    // This adds a data array if it hasn't been created yet.
    if StorageManager.getValue(StorageManager.StorageKeys.WeatherData) == nil {
        StorageManager.setValue([:], forKey: StorageManager.StorageKeys.WeatherData)

    }

    var weatherData: [NSDate: NSObject] = StorageManager.getValue(StorageManager.StorageKeys.WeatherData)! as! [NSDate : NSObject]
    let startMidnight: NSDate = StorageManager.getValue(StorageManager.StorageKeys.WeatherStartDate) as! NSDate
    let currentMidnight: NSDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
    let daysFromStartDate: Int = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: startMidnight, toDate: currentMidnight, options: nil).day
    println("Starting Loop")
    for i: Int in 0..<daysFromStartDate {

        let dateToBeExamined: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, value: i, toDate: startMidnight, options: nil)!
        if weatherData[dateToBeExamined] == nil {
            let calendarUnits: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear
            let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(calendarUnits, fromDate: dateToBeExamined)
            var month: String
            var day: String
            if components.month < 10 {
                month = "0\(components.month)"
            } else {
                month = "\(components.month)"
            }
            if components.day < 10 {
                day = "0\(components.day)"
            } else {
                day = "\(components.day)"
            }
            var dateString = "\(components.year)\(month)\(day)"
            self.baseURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/91e65f0fbb35f122/history_\(dateString)/q/OR/Portland.json"
            println(self.baseURL)
            var get: () = WeatherManager.sharedInstance.addData()
            println(get)
            weatherData[dateToBeExamined] = self.data




            // There is no data for the NSDate dateForInspection. You need to pull data and add it to the dictionary.
        } else {
            // Data exists for the specified date, so you don't need to do anything.
        }
    }
    println("Loop has finished or been skipped")

}

}
```

The problem is, baseURL reverts to an empty string when **getRandomUser** is executed, after baseURL is set to the URL. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code where `baseURL` is set to anything other than a non-empty string after being initialised. Are you sure it contained a non-empty string **before** `getRandomUser(_:)` is called?

Comment: Let me elaborate...The **updateWeatherHistory** function is executed first, in which the baseURL value is set to the URL, then **addData** is executed, in which **getRandomUser** is executed.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint at the line `self.baseURL = "http://api.wunderground.com...` to check that `baseURL` is actually being set?

Comment: Right after baseURL is set to the API, it is printed to the console, and I see the API. However, when getRandomUser is executed, the next thing to happen, baseURL is printed again, but it prints an empty string.

Comment: I think we need to see the code where you set `baseURL` to something other than an empty string. Also, `baseURL` is not a global variable - it is a property of an instance of the `WeatherManager` class. Is it possible that you are creating two instances of `WeatherManager`, and changing the value of `baseURL` for one, but not the other? It appears that you want a `WeatherManager` to be a singleton, but you don't prevent multiple instances of it from being created...

Comment: All of the code is there...`baseURL`'s value is changed in the lower half of `updateWeatherHistory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily complex, making it hard to diagnose the problem without more information. But here is a suggestion:

Try making it impossible to instantiate more than one instance of your `WeatherManager` singleton:

```
class WeatherManager {

    private static let _sharedInstance = WeatherManager()

    private init() { super.init() }

    static func sharedInstance() -> WeatherManager {
        return _sharedInstance
    }
}
```

When you are working from outside `WeatherManager`, you access it by calling:

```
let wm = WeatherManager.sharedInstane()
```

Then, when you are working inside `WeatherManager`, make sure that all your references are to `self` - i.e., `self.baseURL = ...` or `self.updateWeatherHistory()`, instead of `WeatherManager.sharedInstance.baseURL = ...`, etc.

Though your code is complicated, I think what is going on is you actually have two instances of `WeatherManager` in play. You are setting the value of `baseURL` on one, but not the other. If you want it to be a singleton, you need to make it impossible to create more than one.

Comment: I've encountered another issue after implementing your solution: the app loads forever. What does that mean?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that's hard to say, friend :) I would guess that now you've got some kind of infinite recursion going on, but I don't know how to tell you where. I would start by commenting out sections of the code and then uncommenting them one at a time until you find the cause.

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with testing on a simulator? Because I didn't change anything, and it started working again, after testing it 10 or so times.

Comment: I don't know. I would suggest resetting the simulator completely, doing a clean build, then run it and see what happens.